# Remote access to local MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I want to connect to MySQL. Unfortunately target server is accessible only from localhost. It is able to work around for example by uploading some PHP script on the server? I mean a single file rather than the entire PHPMyAdmin or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

can you please elaborate more about your issue?

If you want to connect to mysql server remotely then you need to grant user in mysql users table with your local system IP range.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ssh tunneling for that here is a [link](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html)

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 root@remote-mysql
```

The syntax is

```
ssh -L <localport>hostname<remoteport> <username>@<servername>.
```

We’re using localhost as the hostname because we are directly accessing the remote mysql server through ssh. You could also use this technique to port-forward through one ssh server to another server.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using ssh to tunnel the connection through your local host .. Will need to know a bit about your network layout

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 geek@webserver.com
```